# How to use 'Get' method in rest angular js using 'service' mehtod without using http.get (probably using restangular js)

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have used 'service' method to call a post method.

```
userServices.users(Restangular).post(data);
```

where 
userServices is my factory function and 
users is a function inside it.

```
app.factory('userServices', function ($http,$rootScope,cookie) {
       return{
           users: function(Restangular)
           {
               return Restangular.service('api/authenticate');
           }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
app.factory('Test', function ($http) {
  function getData(data, callback) {
    var url = "URL";
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
      cachedData = data.results;
      callback(data.results);
    });
  }

  return {
    list: getData,
  };
});
```

Comment: Can we write this piece of code without http.get method

Comment: you can create a service for get, then you can directly call that service.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

```
app.service('ObjectService', function($resource) {
    var _service = {};
    _service.Data = function(path) {
        return $resource(path, null, 
            {
                'create': {method:'POST'},
                'get': {method:'GET'},
                'query': {method:'GET', isArray:true},
                'update': { method:'PUT' },
                'remove': {method:'DELETE'}
            }
        );
    };
    return _service;
});
```

and call that

```
var Test = ObjectService.Data('[end-point]/api/test');
Test.get(function(result) { //some manipulation });
```